# Caption label font / how to write caption with bf and sc

Tags: captions

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont={bf,sc},figurename=Fig.,tablename=Tableau]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[!b]
\caption{thermal conductivity}
\label{tab-CT1}
\begin{center}
\small{
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{3cm}@{}*{6}{X@{}}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{couleur primaire} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{couleur secondaire} \\
\cmidrule[.8pt](r{10pt}){2-4} \cmidrule[.8pt]{5-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & rouge & vert & bleu &  jaune & magenta & cyan \\
\midrule[1pt]
composition & R & V & B & RV & RB & VB \\
perméabilité& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4  & 7  & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you remove the `lmodern` package to switch from latin modern to computer modern font, you'll get bold small caps.

Comment: But i need lmodern package

Comment: Can you specify why you need latin modern fonts and if you can change to another font which has bold small caps?

Comment: I need it for the Chapter font

Comment: Off-topic: (a) `left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm` may be expressed more succinctly as `hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=3cm`. (b) `\multicolumn{1}{l}{}` and `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` could be replaced with blanks.

Comment: @NassimeYassine Latin Modern fonts are mostly the same as Computer Modern, so it's difficult to understand what you mean by “I need Latin Modern for the chapter font”. Anyway, you should consider not using boldface *and* small caps: double emphasis is too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could switch back to computer modern font for the caption label:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{textcomp,lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[figurename=Fig.,tablename=Tableau]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{quack}{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{bx}\scshape\selectfont}
\captionsetup{labelfont={quack}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{tabularx}



\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[!b]
\caption{thermal conductivity}
\label{tab-CT1}
\begin{center}
\small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}p{3cm}@{}*{6}{X@{}}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{couleur primaire} & \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{couleur secondaire} \\
\cmidrule[.8pt](r{10pt}){2-4} \cmidrule[.8pt]{5-7}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & rouge & vert & bleu &  jaune & magenta & cyan \\
\midrule[1pt]
composition & R & V & B & RV & RB & VB \\
perméabilité& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4  & 7  & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Warning for future readers. This answer exploits that Computer Modern fonts are mostly the same as Latin Modern, so nobody would spot the difference. But if your document uses a different main font than Latin Modern and this font family hasn't the required shape and weight combinations, substituting it with Computer Modern should be out of the question.